# What's the best way to trigger a child emit from the parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Right now I'm passing a `trigger prop` from the parent to child component, which triggers the `emit` from the child to the parent.

**`parent component`**:

```
<form @submit.prevent="state.store=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <child-component :triggerEmit=state.store @emitSomething="getSomething()"/>
```

**`child component`**:

```
const emit = defineEmits([
    'emitBody'
])

watchEffect(async () => {
    if (props.triggerEmit) {
        emit('emitSomething', value)
    }
})
```

This gets confusing quickly, if the components grow in size and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to trigger `child emits` from the parent, since this seems to be a common use case.

**Edit**:

Trying to trigger the `child method` directly from the parent (not working).

**`child`**:

```
const childMethod = () => {
    console.log('check')
}
```

**`parent`**:

html:

```
  <child ref="childRef"/>
```

script setup:

```
const childRef = ref()

childRef.value.childMethod()
```

Page throws error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childMethod')
```

Comment: In Vue, we use the props down/emit up pattern: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html There is no better way per-se. Vue3 is even more explicit as of what it emits (`defineEmits`), so that one should be enough.

Comment: This example shows a roundabout way of the parent triggering `getSomething()`. Why can't the parent just call its own `getSomething()` directly without even touching the child?

Comment: @tony19 The parent needs an input from the child component. How would I send the input to the parent without a `submit` signal?

Comment: Ok, the example doesn't demonstrate that because `@emitSomething="getSomething()"` ignores the event argument. If you need the child data, the child could implement a `v-model` for it so that the parent could track the data and call `getComponent()` with it whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to access multiple child component methods/properties from the parent component. If Yes, you can achieve that by create a ref and access the methods.

In template **:**

```
<!-- parent.vue -->
<template>
    <button @click="$refs.childComponentRef.childComponentMethod()">Click me</button>
    <child-component ref="childComponentRef" />
</template>
```

In script **:**

With Vue 2 **:**

```
this.$refs.childComponentRef.childComponentMethod( );
```

With Vue 3 Composition Api **:**

```
setup( )
{
    const childComponentRef = ref( );

    childComponentRef.value.childComponentMethod( )

    return {
       childComponentRef
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what the upside of this approach is?

Comment: If you have multiple child's and want to access the properties/methods then you can achieve easily.

Comment: I've tried your approach. Please see the `edit section`.

Comment: Which vue version you are using ?

Comment: Vue 3 with `script setup`

Comment: Did you imported `ref` ? `import { ref } from "vue"`

Comment: Yes, I've imported it

Comment: Then, It should work :( Can you try to debug

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the parent's trigger is effectively querying the child for its event data so that it could call `getSomething()` on it. The parent already owns `getSomething()`, so it really only needs the child data.

Another way to get that data is to use `v-model` to track the child data:

1. In the child component, [implement `v-model`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model) for a prop (a string for example) by declaring a `modelValue` prop and emitting an `'update:modelValue'` event with the new value as the event data:

```html
<!-- ChildName.vue -->
<script setup>
defineProps({ modelValue: String })
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<template>
  <label>Name
    <input type="text" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
  </label>
</template>
```

2. In the parent, add a [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) object, containing a field for each child's `v-model`:

```html
<!-- ParentForm.vue -->
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const formData = reactive({
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  address: {
    city: '',
    state: '',
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <child-name v-model="formData.name" />
    <child-age v-model="formData.age" />
    <child-address v-model:city="formData.address.city" v-model:state="formData.address.state" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

3. Now, the parent can call `getSomething()` on each field upon submitting the form:

```html
<!-- ParentForm.vue -->
<script setup>
import { toRaw } from 'vue'
⋮
const getSomething = field => {
  console.log('getting', field)
}

const submit = () => {
  Object.entries(toRaw(formData)).forEach(getSomething)
}
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    ⋮
  </form>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-child-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FParentForm.vue)

Comment: As always, thank you for your help. Is it possible that you forgot something in the parent? To make it work, I had to do declare the children like so: `<child-name v-model="formData.name" @update:modelValue="doSomething">`.

Comment: Is `doSomething()` different from `getSomething()`? Can you show a more concrete example of where you would need that?

Comment: sorry, I meant `getSomething`